# Prove that $X \in \mathcal{L}^p$ if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n})$ is finite.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

I have the following problem on my problem set:

[image]

I approached the problem this following way, which I think is the right path but I'm still struggling:

> We have $A_{n} = \{n-1\leq |X| < n\}$ and we know that $X \in \mathcal{L}^p$ if $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ is finite. For every $\omega \in A_{n}$, it holds that $(n-1)^p\leq |X|^p < n^p$. For any $\omega \in \Omega$, since $(A_{n})$ defines a partition:
>   \begin{gather*}
>  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)^p 1_{A_{n}} \leq |X|^p < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p 1_{A_{n}}\\
>  \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n}) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|^p) < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n})
> \end{gather*}
>   Now, if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n})$ is finite, it implies that $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ is also finite, which means that $||X||_{p} =  [\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)]^{1/p} < +\infty$ and $X \in \mathcal{L}^p$.

This is only halfway. Now I need to prove that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}n^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n})$ if finite, then $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ is also finite. I procede the following way:

> Using the above inequalities, if $\mathbb{E}(|X|^p)$ finite, then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n})$ is finite and also is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n)^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n+1})$ since we also have that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n)^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n+1}) \leq \mathbb{E}(|X|^p) < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n+1)^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n+1})$. The same logic tells us that  $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n)^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n+1}) < \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(n)^p \mathbb{P}(A_{n})$.

I couldn't compare anything else in order to achieve the result. Any ideas? Am I on the right path? Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: You proved almost everything. You may use the inequality $$ n^p \leq 2^p((n-1)^p + 1) \qquad \text{for } n\geq 1$$ to complete the proof.

Comment: Sorry, I can't see how that helps :/ Isn't that $2^p$ going to make everything get explosive? And is that a well-known inequality such that I should get embarrassed about not knowing? hahaha Thanks a lot!

Comment: The inequality above gives $$ \sum_{n\geq 1} n^p \Bbb{P}(A_n) \leq 2^p \bigg( \underbrace{\sum_{n\geq 1} (n-1)^p \Bbb{P}(A_n)}_{<\infty} + \underbrace{\sum_{n\geq 1} \Bbb{P}(A_n)}_{\leq 1} \bigg) < \infty. $$ And as far as the inequality is concerned, it useful for $L^p$-theory when you are not required to achieve sharp bounds. Proof is also easy: if $x, y \geq 0$ and $p > 0$ then $$ (x + y)^p \leq (2\max\{x, y\})^p = 2^p \max\{x^p, y^p\} \leq 2^p(x^p + y^p). $$ Of course this inequality is not sharp. For $p \geq 1$, you can check that $2^p$ can be replaced by the sharp bound $2^{p-1}$.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks again!!